# How do I pass google maps object into my Self Invoking JS function?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, scope, self-invoking-function

I have simplified the example for this question,but it cannot find the Google maps object.
it returns TypeError:a is null.

Any ideas? I presume its a scope issues or something but am completetly stuck

Thanks for any thoughts.

```
(function ($, document){

    mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),mapOptions);

})(jQuery, document);
```

Comment: is there a element with id "map_canvas" when your code runs?

Comment: in the html there is yeah -  <div id="map_canvas"></div>

Comment: For what reason do you use that self-invoking function at all? There seems to be no point in that as you don't use local vars

Comment: it's going to bepart of a much larger set of functions. But can't even get off the ground at the moment!

Comment: Are you sure Google's script is already loaded? And no, `google` is a valid global variable

Comment: There may be an element with id "map_canvas", but is it there (has it been added to the DOM, has the page finished loading when your code runs)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that your code runs when the page is still being loaded. It's possible that the maps library of google hasn't been loaded yet.

You have to use a construction like this:

```
(function ($, document){
    google.load("maps", function () {
        // here maps is guaranteed to be available
    });
    // here maps may _not_ be available
})(jQuery, document);
```

Comment: ok that's interesting. would I wrap that around my (function ($, document){ ... })() ?

Comment: It doesn't really matter which way you wrap it. `(function ($, document){ ... })()` just makes a new scope (and renames `jQuery` to `$`. But these kinds of statements are usually the top most, so my recommendation is to put `google.load` within your `(function() { }())`.

Comment: thanks I see what your saying, however that returns TypeError: google.load is not a function ?

Comment: Oh, I don't know the name of the actual function, I thought it was `load` though. Check the Google API.

Comment: ah ok fair enough, i get the logic though thanks for your help :)